# Analytically solving of two coupled second order nonlinear ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

I have two coupled non linear second order differential equation.

```
-y1''[x] == + Exp[k1 (y1[x] - y2[x])] - Exp[-k2 (y1[x] - y2[x])],
-y2''[x] == - Exp[k1 (y1[x] - y2[x])] + Exp[-k2 (y1[x] - y2[x])]
```

I have been trying to solve it for past two weeks. Of course, I could get the numeric solution, but I am not able to get analytical solution. So, I was wondering if someone could help me how to solve this analytically so that I can get solution in terms of `y1` and `y2`. Any solution to this problem would be of interest.

I am completely new to Mathematica, so any example worksheets on this sort of equation would be gratefully appreciated!

Comment: Your code has syntax issues you have to use Exp instead of exp. Also, function arguments should be inside square brackets.[ ... ] But that apart, I don't think DSolve can solve non-linear coupled ODEs.

Comment: Analytical solving seems impossible.

Comment: However, I find that $ y_1 + y_2 = a_+ x + b_+, y_1 - y_2 \sim -a_- \sin(b_-  x) $, the 2nd one being a fitted approximation, where $ a_\pm, b_\pm $ are constants to be determined.

Comment: @ Αλέξανδρος Ζεγγ Is your second approximation the solution of the linearized ode assuming `y1-y2` to be small?  If so I would expect  `y1-y2->0 for x-> \[Infinity]` , which is only possible for `b_==0`!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann No, I didn't make such an assumption. Actually, I used `NDSolve` with some values set for $ k_1, k_2 $ as well as some initial values for $ y_1(0), y_1'(0), y_2(0), y_2'(0) $ and I found that then $ y_1 - y_2 $ looked like something as a sine.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3):

Although, as noted in comments above, no symbolic solution appears to exist for general parameters, some progress can be made.  Define

```
eq1 = y1''[x] + Exp[k1 (y1[x] - y2[x])] - Exp[-k2 (y1[x] - y2[x])];
eq2 = y2''[x] - Exp[k1 (y1[x] - y2[x])] + Exp[-k2 (y1[x] - y2[x])];
```

Then, also as noted in a comment,

```
eq1 + eq2 == 0
(* y1''[x] + y2''[x] == 0 *)
```

suggesting the substitution

```
eqw = Simplify[eq1 /. {y2 -> Function[x, -w[x] + c1 + c2 x], 
    y1 -> Function[x, w[x] + c1 + c2 x]}]
(* E^(2 k1 w[x]) - E^(-2 k2 w[x]) + w''[x] *)
```

which `DSolve` can solve, up to a point, yielding an implicit solution in terms of an integral.

```
DSolve[eqw == 0, w, x] // First
(* Integrate[1/Sqrt[2*(-E^(2*k1*K[1])/(2*k1) - 1/(2*E^(2*k2*K[1])*k2)) + C[1]], 
   {K[1], 1, w[x]}]^2 == (x + C[2])^2 *)
```

Explicit solutions exist in at least two cases,

```
FullSimplify[eqw /. k2 -> k1];
Flatten@DSolve[% == 0, w[x], x];
(* {w[x] -> -((I JacobiAmplitude[I Sqrt[k1] Sqrt[-2 + k1 C[1]] (x + C[2]),
            -(4/(-2 + k1 C[1]))])/k1), 
    w[x] -> (I JacobiAmplitude[I Sqrt[k1] x Sqrt[-2 + k1 C[1]] + 
            I Sqrt[k1] Sqrt[-2 + k1 C[1]] C[2], -(4/(-2 + k1 C[1]))])/k1} *)

FullSimplify[eqw /. k2 -> -k1];
Flatten@DSolve[% == 0, w[x], x]
(* {w[x] -> C[1] + x C[2]} *)
```